# How to add a new thumbnail size only to a certain custom post type?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I know how to add a new thumbnail size to my custom plugin. But i want to know if is possible to restrict de new size only to a certain custom post type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cant without editing core files but you can name it any way you want so you can call it 
from you plugin:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'my-plugin-thumb', 220, 180, true );
}
```

and call it

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'my-plugin-thumb' );
}
```

it's not perfect but its something.